# JQuery autocomplete feature Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, url.action

There are many links on this issue but none of them are helping and I am using the below simple JQuery Code, I have tried with CDN too- google CDN, it is giving same error and my autocomplete functionality not working.

Getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`

Source Code:

`

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetStudents")'
        });
    });
</script>`
```

Comment: This is thesource code that I am using:                                                   <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetStudents")'
        });


    });
</script>

Comment: Please format your code correctly by either wrapping your code in `backticks` or by indenting with 4 spaces.

Comment: Please find the formatted Code `<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" > $(function () { $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({ source: '@Url.Action("GetStudents")' }); }); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jquery ui library?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes , here is the code that I am using                                                     `<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function () {
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("GetStudents")'
            });
        });
    </script>`